# Passing value from JS to HTML and then using that value to pass back to JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am running a JS function and at the end of the function I want to send a value through to my HTML to keep a memory of the last value used. I then want to call the JS function again and send the value that I passed to it last back through.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can make sure when the user clicks "New Card" that it won't be repeated. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

I have found items that show how to pass from one way to the other but that's it.

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="card-pull">
    <h2>Your card of the day!</h2>
    <!-- The card image will display below -->
    <img src="" alt="random card pic" id="cardImage">
    </div>
    <div id="cardName">
      <!-- The card name will display here -->
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="currentCardNumber" id="currentCardNumber" />
    <button onclick="newCard(currentCardNumber)">New Card</button>
    <script src="cardpull.js"></script>
  </div>

function newCard(currentCardNumber = 0) {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log(currentCardNumber);
  if (randomNumber == currentCardNumber) {
    newCard(currentCardNumber);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("currentCardNumber").value = randomNumber;
    document.getElementById("cardImage").src = Object.values(
      cards[randomNumber]
    )[1];
    document.getElementById("cardName").innerHTML = Object.values(
      cards[randomNumber]
    )[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out another way (probably a better option) to do what I was trying to do. I was able to get JS to get the value of what was in the HTML code by getting the .innerHTML attribute.

By doing this, I was able to compare the current value on the screen with the value that would be posted from the random draw. Then I had my function check to see if they matched and if so it would run the function again. My code is below (including the array of objects). Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this but It's definitely working out now.

HTML

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="card-pull">
    <h2>Your card of the day!</h2>
    <!-- The card image will display below -->
    <img src="" alt="random card pic" id="cardImage">
    </div>
    <div id="cardName">
      <!-- The card name will display here -->
    </div>
    <button onclick="newCard()">New Card</button>
    <script src="cardpull.js"></script>
  </div>
```

JS

```
const cards = [
  { blackSesame: "Black Sesame", image: "images/blacksesame.jpg" },
  { carrots: "Carrots", image: "images/carrots.jpg" },
  { cilantro: "Cilantro", image: "images/cilantro.jpg" },
  { papaya: "Papaya", image: "images/papaya.jpg" },
  { rosemary: "Rosemary", image: "images/rosemary.jpg" },
];

function newCard() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  const currentCard = document.getElementById("cardName").innerHTML;

  if (currentCard == Object.values(cards[randomNumber])[0]) {
    newCard();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cardImage").src = Object.values(
      cards[randomNumber]
    )[1];
    document.getElementById("cardName").innerHTML = Object.values(
      cards[randomNumber]
    )[0];
  }
}
```